# Disable/Enable a text box based on radio/select option selected Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable an input field in HTML if a radio button has a particular value. I have used Javascript functions for the same.

CODE SNIPPET 1 : (HTML RADIO BUTTON)

```
<div class="element-radio">
    <label class="title">Children</label>
    <div class="column column2">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="children" value="Yes" onChange="findselected()"/>
            <span>Yes</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>

    <div class="column column2">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="children" value="No" checked="checked" onChange="findselected()"/>
            <span>No</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>

<div class="element-number">
    <label class="title">No of children</label>
    <div class="item-cont">
        <input class="large" type="text" min="0" max="100" name="no_children" placeholder="If YES, Number of Children?" value="<?php echo $no_children?>" />
        <span class="icon-place"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CODE SNIPPET 2 : (JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findselected() { 
   if (document.form.children.value == 'No') {
      document.form.no_children.disabled=true;
//      return false;  // not sure this line is needed
   } else {
      document.form.no_children.disabled=false;
//      return false;  // not sure this line is needed
   }
} 
</script>
```

This does not work in the required way. Is there a better way to go about doing the same? I'm fairly new to Javascript so I wouldn't be able to implement a complicated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your script with the following code:

```
function findselected() { 
    var result = document.querySelector('input[name="children"]:checked').value;
    if(result=="Yes"){

        document.getElementById("inputtext").setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("inputtext").removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
}
```

And add `id` attribute in your input control as `id="inputtext"`.

```
<input id="inputtext" class="large" type="text" min="0" max="100" name="no_children" placeholder="If YES, Number of Children?" value="<?php echo $no_children?>" />
```

Comment: Works!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would I define my result variable using query selector for select option html tag?

Comment: You can use :  `document.querySelector('#age option:checked').value`, where `age` is id for select HTML tag.

Comment: You can learn more about **querySelector** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: `document.getElementById("inputtext").disabled = result=="Yes"` could replace the if/else structure. In any case, setting the `.disabled` property to `true` or `false` is better than adding and removing the attribute.